# Split DateTime interval to single days

Tags: php, date-format, dateinterval

I have a PHP script which receives a set of Events from a database with begin/end DateTimes, which represent working times.

```
Begin               | End
2013-08-14 10:00:00 | 2013-08-22 09:30:00
2013-08-08 07:00:00 | 2013-08-08 15:00:00
2013-08-09 07:00:00 | 2013-08-10 07:00:00
```

Now I want to calculate how much has been worked each single day. For the first row I would want an output like that:

```
Begin               | End
2013-08-14 10:00:00 | 2013-08-14 23:59:59
2013-08-15 00:00:00 | 2013-08-15 23:59:59
2013-08-16 00:00:00 | 2013-08-16 23:59:59
....
2013-08-22 00:00:00 | 2013-08-22 09:30:00
```

I've seen some things with DatePeriod and DateInterval, but those didn't take time into account.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are these dates stored in a mysql database table as timestamps, by any chance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[DatePeriod](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) and [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) DO take time into account, so you can use those classes.

Your data :

```
$intervals = [
    ['begin' => '2013-08-14 10:00:00', 'end' => '2013-08-22 09:30:00'],
    ['begin' => '2013-08-08 07:00:00', 'end' => '2013-08-08 15:00:00'],
    ['begin' => '2013-08-09 07:00:00', 'end' => '2013-08-10 07:00:00'],
];
```

Quick function I wrote :

```
function explodePeriodByDays($begin, $end) {
    $days = [];
    $dayInterval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $begin = new DateTime($begin);
    $end = new DateTime($end);
    $_end = clone $end; 
    $_end->modify('+1 day');
    foreach ((new DatePeriod($begin, $dayInterval, $_end)) as $i => $period) {
        $_begin = $period;
        if ($i) $_begin->setTime(0, 0, 0);
        if ($_begin > $end) break;
        $_end = clone $_begin;
        $_end->setTime(23, 59, 59);
        if ($end < $_end) $_end = $end;
        $days[] = [
            'begin' => $_begin,
            'end' => $_end,
        ];
    }
    return $days;
}
```

Example of function use :

```
foreach ($intervals as $interval) {
    echo "Day intervals from {$interval['begin']} to {$interval['end']} : \n";
    foreach (explodePeriodByDays($interval['begin'], $interval['end']) as $day) {
        echo "\t {$day['begin']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')} | {$day['end']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}\n";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output of the example :

```
Day intervals from 2013-08-14 10:00:00 to 2013-08-22 09:30:00 : 
     2013-08-14 10:00:00 | 2013-08-14 23:59:59
     2013-08-15 00:00:00 | 2013-08-15 23:59:59
     2013-08-16 00:00:00 | 2013-08-16 23:59:59
     2013-08-17 00:00:00 | 2013-08-17 23:59:59
     2013-08-18 00:00:00 | 2013-08-18 23:59:59
     2013-08-19 00:00:00 | 2013-08-19 23:59:59
     2013-08-20 00:00:00 | 2013-08-20 23:59:59
     2013-08-21 00:00:00 | 2013-08-21 23:59:59
     2013-08-22 00:00:00 | 2013-08-22 09:30:00

Day intervals from 2013-08-08 07:00:00 to 2013-08-08 15:00:00 : 
     2013-08-08 07:00:00 | 2013-08-08 15:00:00

Day intervals from 2013-08-09 07:00:00 to 2013-08-10 07:00:00 : 
     2013-08-09 07:00:00 | 2013-08-09 23:59:59
     2013-08-10 00:00:00 | 2013-08-10 07:00:00
```

Comment: Exactly like I wanted it to be, thank you. However replacing the [] for array() would make PHP 5.3 sufficient for this task and would not require 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly, you want to get the difference between a begin date and an end date.

I would go about converting the time with a strtotime, subtract the timestamps, then output the date.

```
$begin = strtotime("2013-08-14 10:00:00");
$end   = strtotime("2013-08-14 23:59:59");

$difference = ($end - $begin);

echo gmdate("H:i:s", $difference);
```

This would give you the time in hours, minutes, then seconds.